# JQuery UI - Form doesn't open if autoOpen: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI and I have a dialog box that I want to appear when a button is clicked. When autoOpen is set to true, it will display as soon as page loads and it will open and close. If it is set to false it will not open at all.

**The JQuery UI code is at the bottom of this code block**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        retrieveNotes().done(function (data) {
            $.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
                DataArray[i] = [];
                DataArray[i][0] = item.NotesID.trim();
                DataArray[i][1] = item.NotesTitle.trim();
                DataArray[i][2] = item.NotesText.trim();
                DataArray[i][3] = item.ProfileName.trim();
                DataArray[i][4] = item.IsShared;
                DataArray[i][5] = item.NameOfUser.trim();
            });

            // GRID LOGIC HERE
            var tbl = $("#notes_table");
            var obj = $.paramquery.tableToArray(tbl);

            var newObj = {
                width: 720, height: 300, sortIndx: 0,
                editable: false,
                flexHeight: false,
                title: "Here are your notes for this profile</b>",
                freezeCols: 1, resizable: false, selectionModel: { type: 'row' }, editModel: { clicksToEdit: 2 },
                selectionModel: { mode: 'single' }
            };


            // MUST DECLARE CORRECT NUMBER OF COL PROPERTIES OTHERWISE NULL REFERENCE
            obj.colModel = [
                { title: "Note ID", width: 50, dataType: "string" },
                { title: "Note Title", width: 255, dataType: "string" },
                { title: "Note Text", width: 255, dataType: "string" },
                { title: "Name of Profile", width: 200, dataType: "string" },
                { title: "Is Shared Profile", width: 10, dataType: "boolean" },
                { title: "Note created by:", width: 255, dataType: "string" },
            ];

            newObj.dataModel = { data: DataArray, paging: "local", rPP: 15, rPPOptions: [10, 15, 20, 50, 100] };
            newObj.colModel = obj.colModel;

            //Hide GUID column from user but have it on DOM for edit/delete commands

            newObj.colModel[0].hidden = true;
            newObj.colModel[1].width = 255;
            newObj.colModel[2].hidden = true;
            newObj.colModel[3].width = 200;
            newObj.colModel[4].width = 10;
            newObj.colModel[5].width = 255;

            //append or prepend the CRUD toolbar to .pq-grid-top or .pq-grid-bottom
            $("#divGrid").on("pqgridrender", function (evt, obj) {
                var $toolbar = $("<div class='pq-grid-toolbar pq-grid-toolbar-crud'></div>").appendTo($(".pq-grid-top", this));

                $("<span>Add</span>").appendTo($toolbar).button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus" } }).click(function (evt) {
                    addRow();
                });
                $("<span>Edit</span>").appendTo($toolbar).button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-pencil" } }).click(function (evt) {
                    editRow();
                });
                $("<span>Delete</span>").appendTo($toolbar).button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-circle-minus" } }).click(function () {
                    deleteRow();
                });
                $toolbar.disableSelection();
            });

            $grid = $("#divGrid").pqGrid(newObj);


            //create popup dialog.
            $("#popup-dialog-crud").dialog({
                width: 400, modal: true,
                open: function () { $(".ui-dialog").position({ of: "#divGrid" }); },
                autoOpen: false
            });

            //buildGrid(DataArray);
        });
    });
```

**My HTML**

```
  <div id="popup-dialog-crud" style="width: auto; min-height: 47px; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
                <form id="crud-form">
                    <table align="center">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Company Name:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="company"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Symbol:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="symbol"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Price:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="price"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Change:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="change"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">%Change:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="pchange"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="label">Volume:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="volume"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#popup-dialog-crud" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2Kvj8/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I feel like an idiot that I didn't include this click event handler. I copied this code from ParamQuery and they didn't have this in their example.